# How to perform api tests in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, testing

I have a kubernetes pod with some rest service running. Now i have a seperate project which consist out of api tests that will test the functionality against this rest service. The goal is to setup a azure pipeline that will deploy a docker image in the kubernetes cluster where the tests will run. But I'm not sure on how this works....

Basically I need to create a seperate pod from my test project docker image right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying a separate pod would work. However, note that you can also use [mirrord](https://mirrord.dev) to connect your test runner directly to the Kubernetes cluster. It would save you building + deploying the image, and might make reporting the test results easier too.